# How to create Category / Subcategory Friendly URL in PrestaShop?

Tags: prestashop

I have a question about formatting the friendly URL for category and subcategory and getting the matching products. I am using PrestaShop 1.5.2.0

Let's say we have a structure like this:

**Category 1**

- Spare Parts
- Accessories

**Category 2**

- Chips
- Accessories

I want to display the link like this: **/category-1/accessories** and to display the products from category 1->accessories. How can I achieve this?

The current behavior is when I click on accessories, being in category 1, the link is **/accessories** and the products that are displayed belong from both /category-1/accessories and /category-2/accessories

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered on the PrestaShop forum. 
You can find it here http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/220017-category-subcategory-url/

The solution - add this changes to the fallowing classes

**CLASSES/Dispatcher.php**

```
'rule' => '{categories:/}{id}-{rewrite}/',
'categories' => array('regexp' => '[/_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
```

**CLASSES/Link.php**

```
$cats = array();    
foreach ($category->getParentsCategories() as $cat)    
if (!in_array($cat['id_category'], array(1, 2, $category->id)))//remove root, home and current category from the URL    
$cats[] = $cat['link_rewrite'];    
$params['categories'] = implode('/', array_reverse($cats));
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is valid for the older versions, but it would not work for the newer/latest version. I updated the same solution for the newer version (1.7.7.4.), it might be used for others.

change CLASSES/`Dispatcher.php`

at about line 55 in the above file copy paste

```
public $default_routes = [
        'category_rule' => [
            'controller' => 'category',
             **/**  added 1 line below*/
            'rule' => '{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}/',
             /** commented   1line below*/
            /**'rule' => '{id}-{rewrite}',*/
            'keywords' => [
                'id' => ['regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_category'],
                /*** added  1 line below*/
                'category' => ['regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'],
                'rewrite' => ['regexp' => self::REWRITE_PATTERN],
                'meta_keywords' => ['regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'],
                'meta_title' => ['regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'],**
            ],
        ],
```

In the file classes/`link.php` find the function `getCategoryLink` and replace it with the function code below

```
 /**
     * Create a link to a category.
     *
     * @param mixed $category Category object (can be an ID category, but deprecated)
     * @param string $alias
     * @param int $idLang
     * @param string $selectedFilters Url parameter to autocheck filters of the module blocklayered
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryLink(
        $category,
        $alias = null,
        $idLang = null,
        $selectedFilters = null,
        $idShop = null,
        $relativeProtocol = false
    ) {
        $dispatcher = Dispatcher::getInstance();

        if (!$idLang) {
            $idLang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        }

        $url = $this->getBaseLink($idShop, null, $relativeProtocol) . $this->getLangLink($idLang, null, $idShop);

        // Set available keywords
        $params = [];

        if (!is_object($category)) {
            $params['id'] = $category;
        } else {
            $params['id'] = $category->id;
        }

        // Selected filters is used by the module ps_facetedsearch
        $selectedFilters = null === $selectedFilters ? '' : $selectedFilters;

        if (empty($selectedFilters)) {
            $rule = 'category_rule';
        } else {
            $rule = 'layered_rule';
            $params['selected_filters'] = $selectedFilters;
        }

        if (!$alias) {
            $category = $this->getCategoryObject($category, $idLang);
        }
        $params['rewrite'] = (!$alias) ? $category->link_rewrite : $alias;
        if ($dispatcher->hasKeyword($rule, $idLang, 'meta_keywords', $idShop)) {
            $category = $this->getCategoryObject($category, $idLang);
            $params['meta_keywords'] = Tools::str2url($category->getFieldByLang('meta_keywords'));
        }
        if ($dispatcher->hasKeyword($rule, $idLang, 'meta_title', $idShop)) {
            $category = $this->getCategoryObject($category, $idLang);
            $params['meta_title'] = Tools::str2url($category->getFieldByLang('meta_title'));
        }
        
        if ($category !='var'){
        $category = $this->getCategoryObject($category, $idLang);
        $pcategory= new Category($category->id_parent, $idLang);
        if($category->id_parent!=1 && $category->id_parent!=2){
            $params['category'] = $pcategory->link_rewrite;
            //append the categoryID with its name
            $params['category'] = $category->id_parent . '-'. $params['category'];
        }
    }
        
        return $url . Dispatcher::getInstance()->createUrl($rule, $idLang, $params, $this->allow, '', $idShop);
    }
```

in the same file classes/link.php  update if condition as follows at line 218 in the code for (function getProductLink)

```
if ($dispatcher->hasKeyword('product_rule', $idLang, 'categories', $idShop)) {
            $product = $this->getProductObject($product, $idLang, $idShop);
            $params['category'] = (!$category) ? $product->category : $category;
            $cats = [];
            
            foreach ($product->getParentCategories($idLang) as $cat) {
                
                if (!in_array($cat['id_category'], Link::$category_disable_rewrite)) {
                    //remove root and home category from the URL
                    //commented the line below 
                    //$cats[] = $cat['link_rewrite'];
                    //replaced the above line with the line below to append the category ID in the products link


                    $cats[] = $cat['id_category'].'-'.$cat['link_rewrite'];
                }
            }
            $params['categories'] = implode('/', $cats);
        }
```

I happened to be using the prestashop version 1.7.7.4. You can see this solution working on my site https://jinbaba.pk

Also after making the above changes in the code files, do not forget to update `shopparameters-->SEO&URL` Setting, change the category and product routes as follows (if they are not already like this)

`"Route to category" = {category:/}{id}-{rewrite}`

`"Route to product" = {categories:/}{id}{-:id_product_attribute}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html`

Just a suggestion for SEO : You do not need to remove category ID and product ID from the URL. They have minimal or no impact on SEO.

also the about solution will work for 2 level nesting e.g.

yourdomain.com/category-1/category-2/1-product.html

do not create more nesting of categories in your catalog. If you plan to do create deeper nesting your site you will need to update this solution. However, for SEO deep nesting is not recommended.